# Como almacenar carácter por carácter en Matriz

Tags: c++, c

Tengo el siguiente algoritmo el cual lee un `archivo.txt`, la primera linea lee 3 enteros el cual almaceno en `movimiento`, `fila`, `columna` y las siguientes lineas son un mapa, el cual quiero almacenar en una matriz la cual estoy creando, pero no tengo la idea de como poder almacenar carácter por carácter en mi matriz.

*archivo.txt*:

```
25 10 4
==========
=x=.=@====
=.#x....x=
==========
```

*Código en `c++`*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void mapa();

int movimientos, fila, columna;
typedef vector< vector<char> > Mapa;

int main() {
    mapa();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void mapa(){
    ifstream archivo;
    string linea;

    archivo.open("Entrada.txt", ios::in); //abrimos el archivo

    if(archivo.fail()){
        cout<<"Ocurrio un error con el archivo.";
        exit(1);
    }

    archivo >> movimientos >> fila >> columna;
    Mapa m(fila, vector<char> (columna));



    while(!archivo.eof()){
        archivo.get(a);
        for(int i = 0; i<fila; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < columna ; ++j)
            {
                m[i][j] = a;
            }
        }
    }       

    cout<<movimientos<<endl;
    cout<<fila<<endl;
    cout<<columna<<endl;

    //imprimo la matriz
    for(int i = 0; i<fila; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < columna ; ++j)
        {
            cout<<"["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]: "<< m[i][j] << " " <<endl;
        }
    }


    archivo.close(); //cerramos el archivo
}
```

Intente usar la funcion `.get` para intentar almacenar uno por uno,pero los almacena mal, solo almacena los `=` de mi mapa.

Que puedo intentar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El programa no está almacenando únicamente los `=` del mapa, está almacenando únicamente el último de ellos.

Fíjate que en el `while` que lee, modificas todo el mapa con la última lectura.

También creo que la lectura de las filas y columnas está al revés, por el archivo de ejemplo, ¿no debería ser lo siguiente?:

```
archivo >> movimientos >> columna >> fila;
```

Luego, puedes utilizar `std::getline()` para leer cada línea del archivo y guardarla en el mapa:

```
archivo.ignore(10, '\n');
Mapa m(fila, vector<char> (columna));

for(int i = 0; i < fila && std::getline(archivo, linea); ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < columna ; ++j)
    {
        m[i][j] = linea[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Me almacena todo bien, menos la ultima fila, la coloca de primero y no de ultimo

Comment: Revísalo ahora que he agregado un `ignore()`, por otro lado revisa el archivo de ejemplo y la lectura de las filas y columnas y dime si estoy en lo cierto.